# How do I select individual flutter ListTiles for a select favorite icon with onPressed?

Tags: listview, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot, staggered-gridview

Here is the entire code that I can't add user favorite list to. I simply want the heart icon to change color when selected as favorite, then push the saved favorite item to a saved favorites page.

I have no idea what else to do, since I must use itemLength. It is not appearing to be possible with streambuilder.

```
class Books extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_BooksState createState() => _BooksState();
}

class _BooksState extends State<Books> {
var firestoreDb = Firestore.instance.collection("books").snapshots();


static final int _itemLength = snapshot.data.documents[index]['title'].length;
List<bool> _isFavorited = List<bool>.generate(_itemLength, (_) => false);


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'Book List',
                style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                  color: Colors.amberAccent.shade50,
                ),
              )),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(MdiIcons.gift, color: Color(0xffffe0b2), size: 32.0),
            onPressed: () {
              _launchURL();
            },
          ),
        ]),
    backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
    elevation: 50.0,
  ), //AppBar

  body: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: firestoreDb,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) Text('Loading...');
          return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0, vertical: 6.0),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, int index) => Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Card(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                    ),

                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          '${(snapshot.data.documents[index]['title'])}',
                          style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            height: 1.2,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),

                        subtitle: Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.share,
                                    color: Colors.amberAccent,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () => Share.share(
                                    '${(snapshot.data.documents[index]['title'])}',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),

                              Expanded(
                                child: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () => setState(() =>
                                  _isFavorited[index] =
                                  !_isFavorited[index]),
                                  icon: _isFavorited[index]
                                      ? Icon(MdiIcons.heart,color: Colors.red)
                                      : Icon(MdiIcons.heartOutline,color: Colors.red,),
                                ),
                              ),

                              Expanded(
                                child: Text(
                                  '${(snapshot.data.documents[index]['subtitle'])}',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                    fontSize: 13.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                    color: Colors.blue,
                                  ),
                                ), //subtitle: Text
                              ),
                            ] //children
                        ), //Row
                      ), //listtile
                    ]),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.fit(2),
          );
        }),
  ),
);
} //build
} //class

_launchURL() async {
const url = 'https://amazon.com';
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
await launch(url);
} else {
throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've to maintain the value of `_isFavorited` for all the `ListTiles`. So `bool _isFavorited` should be `List<bool> _isFavorited`. Then you can modify the IconButton's logic as follows:

```
Expanded(
    child: IconButton(
        icon: _isFavorited[index]
            ? Icon(Icons.star)
            : Icon(Icons.star_border),                     
        onPressed: () => setState(() => _isFavorited[index] = !_isFavorited[index]),
    ), 
),
```

I've created a sample demo for this on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/6f373fc90ea482237a3ccba6c86522e2)

Comment: so turn _isfavorited into a list and add .generate? I wasn't aware of that, two days of trying to figure it out and you make it look easy. Thank you. How do I integrate my item length into itemCount , itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length, into static final int _itemLength = 20;

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help. `snapshot.data.documents` is part of `FutureBuilder`?

Comment: I'm using StreamBuilder with firestore data and everything I return for  static final int _itemLength gives error.

Comment: I've updated the DartPad with StreamBuilder usage. You can adjust your code according to your needs.

Comment: If I use any combination in _itemLength =snapshot.data.length, snapshot.data.documents.length; etc., always says first item is not defined, but I am using itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length for my StreamBuilder data. What am I missing, is the a way around having to define item length again in your code, I still can't get it to work.

Comment: I didn't get you.

Comment: your new code, itemLength != null ?  before returning ListView, does not work for me I am using a StagerredGridView.countBuilder.  Your original code looked like the better option but I simply can not define my data length from my Firestore data - I guess this is impossible?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me. I am simply trying to add a clickable icon in my StreamBuilder/StaggeredGridView.countBuilder/ListTile structure with Firestore data (title), and have the clicked selections stored in the app, without rewriting the entire code. But it does not appear to be possible to achieve such a seemingly simple thing in Flutter.

Comment: so this can't be done with a correct item count for StreamBuilder, why is item count even necessary n the code to just make a icon change color?

Comment: Doesn't anyone know how to do this correctly? 5 days of my life wasted finding 500 ways this doesn't work. I quit.

Comment: Why don't you share your code using GitHub? I can help you.

Comment: I don't know how to use github